# How do I take an array of deserialized data and store it into entity framework db?

Tags: c#, sql, xml, entity-framework

I was able to deserialize my data from using a user import an xml file. Now, I'm wondering how do I take the deserialized xml data and store it into my local database using Entity Framework/ADO.NET?

My model:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("lot_information")]
public class LotInformation
{

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("components")]
    [XmlArrayItem("component", typeof(Components))]
    public Components[] components { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("families")]
    [XmlArrayItem("control", typeof(Families))]
    public Families[] families { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("exp_date")]
    public DateTime exp_date { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("lot_number")]
    public string lot_number { get; set; }


}

[Serializable]
public class Components
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("control")]
    public string aControl { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("cal_ref")]
    public string cal_ref { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("family")]
    public string family { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("component")]
    public int component { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string componentId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("target")]
    public int target { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("min")]
    public int min { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("max")]
    public int max { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("number")]
    public int number { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Families
{

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("family")]
    public string controlFamily { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("pctrl")]
    public string pctrl { get; set; }

}
```

My dataContext:

```
 class DMIDataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Components> Components { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Families> Families { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ReagentLotInformation> ReagentLotInformation {get;set;}

    public DMIDataContext() : base("DMIConnectionString")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

My viewmodel:
   Excerpt with db connection:

```
  public static void DeSerializationXML(string filePath)
    {
        XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
        xRoot.ElementName = "lot_information";
        xRoot.IsNullable = false;

        // Create an instance of lotinformation class.
        var lot = new LotInformation();

        // Create an instance of stream writer.
        TextReader txtReader = new StreamReader(filePath);

        // Create and instance of XmlSerializer class.
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LotInformation), xRoot);

        // DeSerialize from the StreamReader
        lot = (LotInformation)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(txtReader);

        // Close the stream reader
        txtReader.Close();

 using (var db = new DMIDataContext())
        {LotInformation newLot = new LotInformation();

            if (newLot != null)
            {
                newLot.Id = lot.Id;
                newLot.lot_number = lot.lot_number;
                newLot.exp_date = lot.exp_date;

          for (int i = 0; i < lot.Components.Length; i++)
                {

                           newLot.Components[i].aControl = lot.Components[i].aControl;
                           newLot.Components[i].cal_ref = lot.Components[i].cal_ref;
                           newLot.Components[i].family = lot.Components[i].family;
                           newLot.Components[i].component = lot.Components[i].component;
                           newLot.Components[i].componentId = lot.Components[i].componentId;
                           newLot.Components[i].target = lot.Components[i].target;
                           newLot.Components[i].min = lot.Components[i].min;
                           newLot.Components[i].number = lot.Components[i].number;

}
                 db.LotInformation.Add(newLot);
                 db.SaveChanges();
```

The problem I'm having is I'm able to pass exp_date and lot_number to my table just fine. It's just the arrays of Components and Families return NULL. I think it has to do with me passing an array of date into the database but the database does not understand an array.

How do I fix my class so that I can pass an array of data into the database?

Please let me know if you have any questions. THank you.

Comment: Could you show the code where you try it

Comment: Updated the code with db connection context?

Comment: Have you tried instead arrays using `ICollection` and then initialize it in the constructor?

Comment: In the case above where I use an array, it says: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I'm not sure how to use an ICollection and what would be the benefit of using an ICollection over an array?

Comment: Because your arrays are not initialized.

Comment: Also, when I tried using an ICollection, I couldn't get my deserialization method working for some reason and I'm not sure why. It works for an array though. I think it might be because XmlSerializer doesn't know what tags to look for using an ICollection. In my case, I used [XmlArray] and it was able to parse through the xml data. When I use [XmlElement] for ICollection, my deserialization method breaks. I think that's why.

Comment: I was expecting this answer

Comment: My array is initialized in my deserialzation method. I used the using db code inside my deserialization method.

Comment: Btw, how would I deserialize an ICollection properly then? Could you give an example? I can post up my deserialization method...

Comment: I updated my post to show you my deserialization method, instantation of lot.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51467/discussion-between-kala-j-and-lnanikian)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:
You can use `List` instead of `ICollection`

```
 [Serializable]
 [XmlRoot("lot_information")]
 public class LotInformation
 {

  Public LotInformation()
  {
    Components = new List<Components>();
    Families = new List<Families>();
  }

 [Key]
 public int Id { get; set; }

 [XmlArray("components")]
 [XmlArrayItem("component", typeof(Components))]
 public List<Components> Components { get; set; }

 [XmlArray("families")]
 [XmlArrayItem("control", typeof(Families))]
 public List<Families> Families { get; set; }

 ....

}
```

And in your ViewModel:

```
using (var db = new DMIDataContext())
    {LotInformation newLot = new LotInformation();

            newLot.Id = lot.Id;
            newLot.lot_number = lot.lot_number;
            newLot.exp_date = lot.exp_date;

      foreach (Components comp in lot.Components)
            {

                       newLot.Components.Add(comp);

             }
      foreach (Families fam in lot.Families)
            {

                       newLot.Families.Add(fam);

             }
             db.LotInformation.Add(newLot);
             db.SaveChanges();
```

I hope it will help.
As you can see in this [link](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/XMLArrays.aspx), you can use List.

Comment: EDIT: Hi again, I figured out what you did wrong! You wrote public as "Public" and you forgot to add () to the LotInformation method:  Public LotInformation()
  {
    Components = new List<Components>();
    Families = new List<Families>();
  }. Otherwise, it works!! Thank you so much!! This frustrated me to no end!! Thank you so much for your help!! Seriously, I spent so many hours on this :D